# API call restriction

Tags: python, api, get, limit, placeholder

I am new to this concept.Currently,I am working on API calls.

Background:

Here is my requirement.
I have a get API url

/details/v1/employee/{employeeid}/employeecodes?%s&limit=5000&offset={1}.

This Url gets one record at a time.So,I need to pass employeeid value to this url in a loop.
I have 300K employee in a list.

Issue:

Issue here is ,I have a limit on API calls that is 25K per day. But I have 300K employee,the program errors out saying out of call volume quota.

Question:
Is there any approach that I can limit my API calls?

Comment: lol no. there is a reason why they have a limit. If you need their data, just send them an email

Comment: Are you sure there's not another API call that will return what you want for multiple employees at a time?

Comment: Thanks @Alex.Will check with the team.

Comment: Thanks @ViennaMike. No,they have not provided another API.